# Re-install networking packages

Tags: ubuntu

I have problems with my network in Ubuntu 13.10.

Since it worked some days ago, and no solution I tried could repair it, I want to install it all over again. That would be kind of a reset to the original configuration.

However, how can I obtain a list of all relevant packages? And second, once I purge the installed packages, how can I get the new ones? I won't have any Internet connection then...

Comment: Purging the packages is impossible because it would break your system, reinstalling them won't reset the configuration and above all reinstalling packages probably won't solve your issue. You will probably have more luck when you post a question describing your issue so that we can solve the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

What things did you try before?

Also seems like you should just get the DVD you used to install the OS originally and use that again. If you don't have one, then I'd simply download it and burn it.

As for what packages you've already installed. Use this command and dump it to a file like so:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages
```

The output looks like this:

```
zenity                                      install
zenity-common                               install
zerofree                                    install
zip                                         install
zlib1g:amd64                                install
zlib1g-dev:amd64                            install
```

You can use this install them later on:

```
$ sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Desktop/packages && sudo apt-get \
     -u dselect-upgrade
```

This approach might be problematic due to the list containing packages, so you might want to trim it ahead of time to only include packages that were "extras" that you installed after the system was initially setup.

#### References

- [How to list all installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)